# Make a regex that spans over multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have looked at the flags and I cloudn't find what I am looking for. Basically if I am searching for:

```
aba
```

It should totally ignore the new lines, so the following things are valid:

```
a
b
a

a


b

a

ab



a
```

Edit: I am aiming at doing something a bit more elegant than putting `\s?` after every character in the regex (given that it is a constant if it is a range than I have no idea what so ever)

Comment: You could remove all the whitespace, if appropriate.

Comment: strip out the newlines from the string - is that not an option before running your regex?

Comment: It can work and I might end up doing it, I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to do it with a regex.

Comment: `str.replace(/\s+/g,'').match(/aba/g);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The simple case**

For your example where the exact letters are `aba`, I would go with

```
a\s*b\s*a
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fI4fC9)

**The more intricate case**

In a comment, you ask about an expression such as `[a-z]{1,5}`, where you presumably want to inject potential spaces between the letters. For this, I would go with

```
(?:[a-z]\s*){1,5}
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pQ9rL9)

Answer (score 2):

```
/a\s*b\s*a/
```

Place whitespace possibilities between each letter.

Comment: and what happens if the regular expression looks like this: [a-z]{1,5}

Comment: @Bloodcount Tough luck, i suppose.

Comment: @Bloodcount, I don't know all the possible scenarios you might have, but for the one you suggested here you could do this: `/([a-z]\s*){1,5}/`

Comment: Actually I had not considered that. Might end up working nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

:)) It's an interesting problem. For this situations I use another method.

1. First I remove all line ending chars:

   someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
2. Use a normal regex